# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { javaScript

Tags: javascript, html

```
import { LoadScene } from "./scenes/LoadScene.js";
```

on this line of code I get this error: 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {'

To deploy code into the browser i use visual studio code's extension 'Live Server'.

All code where import appears:

```
/** @type {import('./../../PHAZER/phaser-3.18.1/types/phaser')} */

import { LoadScene } from "./scenes/LoadScene.js";
import { MenuScene } from "./scenes/MenuScene.js";

let game = new Phaser.Game({
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    scene: [
       LoadScene, MenuScene
    ]
});
```

```
export const CTS = 
{
    SCENES: {
        LOAD: 'LOAD',
        MENU: 'MENU'
    }
}
```

```
import { CTS } from './../CTS.js';
import { MenuScene } from './MenuScene';

export class LoadScene extends Phaser.Scene
{
    constructor(){
        super({
            key: CTS.SCENES.LOAD
        })
    }

    preload() {
        this.load.image("logo", "./../assets/logo.png");
        this.load.image('bg', './../assets/title_bg.jpg');
        this.load.image('playBt', './../assets/play_button.png');
        this.load.image('optionsBt', './../assets/options_button.png');


        let loadingBar = this.add.graphics({
            fillStyle: {
                color: '0xffffff'
            }
        });    

        this.load.on('progress', (percent) => {
            loadingBar.fillRect(0, this.game.renderer.height/2, this.game.renderer.width * percent, 50);
            console.log(percent);
        });
    }
    create() {
        console.log('Hello from LoadScene');
        this.scene.start(CTS.SCENES.MENU, 'Hello from loadScene');
    }
}
```

```
import { CTS } from './../CTS.js';

export class MenuScene extends Phaser.Scene
{
    constructor(){
        super({
            key: CTS.SCENES.MENU
        })
    }

    init(){
        console.log('MenuScene running!');
    }

    preload(){

    }

    create() {
        this.add.image(0, 0,"bg");
    }
}
```

and heres html code where i import (i guess) phaser.js which is engine file (I guess? I just followed tutorials so far)

```html
<!doctype html> 
<html lang="en"> 
<head> 
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>My Game</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            margin: 10;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<script src="./phaser.js"></script> 
<script src='main.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I use parcel for same thing it works but i get some other strange beheviour, and when i use http-server its just downloads html file that its supposed to run when i enter the page.

im working with Phaser 3 on this one

Comment: Are you using an "import" anywhere else? Does your project support es6?

Comment: @James Yea it does, if It matters ill add whole code to question, tbh im new to javascript and html, so I dont really now what ES6 is and if its supported in my project

Comment: Are you sure the HTML page has the script included with `type="module"`?

Comment: Basically there are two types of modules in JS, CommonJS (used in servers, syntax: `const foo = require('foo');`, and ESModules (used in browsers, syntax: `import foo from 'foo'`). Make sure you use the right syntax in the right place. Else, refactor your code, or transpile it using Babel or Webpack.

Comment: Thanks Stanley. Where is the Phaser class being declared? You initiate a new Phaser in the first set of code but I don't see it being imported anywhere.

Comment: Oh yeah I forgot to add index.html (Im really new to all this and dont really know how these things work (I came from C++/SML )